# angular ng-repeat key in internal array of object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have json objects array:

```js
[{id: "gfggf", 
name: "name1", 
users: [{id: "dfgdgdffg", username: "user1"}, {id: "45535", username: "user2"}]}
]
```

and ng-repeat:

```html
 <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
           <h3>{{group.name}}</h3> // name1
         </div>
```

i need show users array, (user1, user2) in ng-repeat. I need most performance way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inner-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
    <h3>{{group.name}}</h3>
    <p ng-repeat="user in group.users">{{user.username}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply nest it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
  <h3>{{group.name}}</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="user in group.users">
    <h4>{{user.username}}</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```